# Django 1.8 Models: get applabel.model string

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this:

core/models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(maxlength=100)
```

Now I need to get the python string representation like this:
'core.country'.
Is there an easier way than this?

```
>>> from core.models import Country    
>>> model = '.'.join([Country._meta.app_label, Country._meta.model_name])
>>> print model
'core.country'
```

I noticed this also works:

```
model = unicode(Country._meta)
```

But I do not want to use it as django might changes this at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django 1.9 you can use [`label_lower`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#label-lower).

In Django 1.8, I would construct the string manually as you have done.